# mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters

Tags: php, mysqli

hello I'm very new at this I'mtrying to learn website building from scratch. this code i copied from another website keeps returning me these errors:

> mysqli_query expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in home/user/public_html/db.php on line 22.

I kinda understand the query its asking for I just cant figure out how to write it 
This is on line 7 in my database script.

```
$result = mysqli_query();
```

the other one I'm having problems with:

> Fatal error:  Call to undefined function valid_email() in /home/user/public_html/register.php on line 7

the script on line 7:

```
if($_POST['username']!='' && $_POST['password']!='' && $_POST['password']==$_POST['password_confirmed'] && $_POST['email']!='' && valid_email($_POST['email'])==TRUE && checkUnique('Username', $_POST['username'])==TRUE && checkUnique('Email', $_POST['email'])==TRUE)
```

I apologize if I'm asking a questions dummies would figure out. I am new this, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Valid email is a function, which you havent define earlier. The function have to be defined earlier before using it. And you have to pass two parameter with $result = mysqli_query(); , one is the connection string and other is query

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_query` expects you to supply two parameters: the first being the MySQL connection and the second being the command to execute in MySQL. More information on the specifics can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php.

The error you're getting is because `valid_email()` is not a system defined function, nor have you defined `valid_email()` as a function, therefore PHP is throwing a `Fatal error` due to it not understanding what you want it to do because it doesn't "know" what `valid_email()` means.

Answer (score 1):

For the query issue, if you use it procedural style (as in not the function of a MySqliConnection object) then you need two parameters (1- db link, 2-the actual query) see doc [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

As for the second, there is no function validate_email. Use this [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)
 ex:

```
filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```